# Is there any way to manipulate elements by ID or class in a different file in the same directory?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know whether it's possible to select and manipulate elements of a given ID or class in a different HTML file in the same directory.  For example, like using `getElementById` but in a different file.

Comment: You mean in the text html of that file, or you mean in the DOM of a rendered page?

Comment: yes it is text html

Comment: You can store some values in localStorage (use json stringify), then at a page load, run some codes based on this values to populate your elements.

Comment: Clarify intent of question/problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these files are on the local machine:

For loading the file:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<textarea id="loadedFileArea"></textarea>

<script>
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event)
        {
            // NOTE: event.target point to FileReader
            var contents = event.target.result;
            document.getElementById('loadedFileArea').innerText = contents;
//            var lines = contents.split('\n');
            //////
//            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=contents;

        };

        reader.readAsText(f);

    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

For saving this back, check out [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) You just need to turn the text (html) contents of loadedFileArea into a blob and pass that into FileSaver.saveAs